# Python: Accessing another class of current module by name

Tags: python

I have the following setup in one module:

```
class A(object):
    # stuff

class B(object):
    # stuff
```

Now what I want to do is, creating an instance of class `A` by name (I just have the class name as a string) inside of `B`. How can I do this avoiding the `globals` function?

Comment: What do you mean with "accessing on class A by name inside"  ?

Comment: I have the class name as a string.

Comment: And .... with that string what have you to do ?

Comment: I want to get an instance of the class

Comment: And why do you not want to use `globals`?

Comment: `globals` isn't really performant, I think. That's why I ask for other ways

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use `A`? Or do you have just a string `'A'`? If yes, `globals()['A']` is the way to go. The alternative would be `getattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'A')` but obviously `globals()` is more appropriate.

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: getattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'Foo'))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (getattr)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (sys)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                2 (modules)
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (__name__)
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR
             13 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Foo')
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             19 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis(lambda: globals()['Foo'])
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (globals)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Foo')
              9 BINARY_SUBSCR
             10 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis(lambda: Foo)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Foo)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

So by just looking at the instructions used for the various ways to access `Foo`, using `globals()` is most likely faster than going through `sys.modules`.

Comment: But what would be faster? I think, globals isn't really performant

Comment: Why do you think so? Does such a most likely negligible performance difference really matter?

Comment: Depends on the performance difference. If it's negligible, `globals` is okay. But I'm not _that_ pro in python ;)

Comment: You could make it even faster by only calling `globals()` once and storing it in a variable. However, I'm still curious why you cannot just use the class itself.

Comment: @Penthi: If you're that concerned with performance, you can cache previously looked up results.

Comment: Okay that is interesting. Thank you for the update on the answer. The class usage depends on settings, to give you a little more context. So I simply can't hard code that.

Answer (score 3):

Let me see if I understand you right:

- You have a settings file that looks something like

  ```
  ...
  connection-type: FooConnection
  ...
  ```
- You have a bunch of classes

  ```
  class FooConnection(Connection): ...
  class BarConnection(Connection): ...
  class BazConnection(Connection): ...
  ```
- You want to map `"FooConnection"` from the settings file to the *class* `FooConnection`.

---

If so, I would do this instead:

- Put

  ```
  connection-type: Foo
  ```

  in the settings file, or some other human-readable name that doesn't depend on the name of the class.
- Write a mapping from human-readable names to implementations:

  ```
  implementations = {
      "Foo": FooConnection,
      "Bar": BarConnection,
      "Baz": BazConnection
  }
  ```

  You can change this mapping if you want to change e.g. how you implement the classes. This also lets you have synonyms.
- Look up the value in the settings file in the implementations dictionary to get the class you want.

---

In fact, you're doing this already. Just, instead of explicitly writing down the mapping of strings to classes, you're using the `globals` dictionary; in other words, assuming that the end user knows the class names you want to use. That's not nice.

Comment: Nice answer! The setting is not visible to the user, it's a project setting. But in that context, I'm not really sure if I could import the class at that point.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear what you mean by "accessing on class A by name", but usually there are three main approaches, depending on what you actually want to do.

1. You create an instance of class A inside class B's `__init__`
2. You inherit from class A in class B
3. What @ThiefMaster posted.

Comment: Inheritance is not really a good way for me and simply access by hard coded also.